# TCPDF WriteHTML() created link is not clickable

Tags: tcpdf

```
 $pdf = new TCPDF();
 $myHTML = '<a href="https://www.google.com/">TEST LINK</a>';
 $pdf->writeHTML($myHTML, true, false, true, false, '');
```

[This is the screenshot of output in PDF from the code above but not clickable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5XFH.png)

Answer (score 1):

Rather old post but if you come across this:

1. First verify that in your setup [example 6](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_006/) is working fine.
2. The also check if your link description has unicode characters. they might mess up things.

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with this one too for a while. For me it worked to change single quotes around the link to double quotes. It's the same with using the write method on a newline character.

If I were to write:

```
$pdf->Write(4, '\n');
```

then I'd see the newline characters printed on the PDF in stead of a return

When I write:

```
$pdf->Write(4, "\n");
```

then the newline gets created.

So, do you have the same behaviour with the double/single quotes. And just for the sake of it, try changing them anyhow and/or remove the final slash from the link.

Alternatively, you can try to change your code to:

```
$pdf->Write(4, 'TEST LINK', 'https://www.google.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

For me worked to use escaped double quotes

```
$html = "<a href=\"http://your.link.com\">Link</a>";
```